# How to write a program that simulates the rolling of two dice 10,000 times

Tags: python

The program should simulate rolling two dice about 10,000
times and compute and print out the percentage of rolls that come out to be 2, 3, 4, . . . , 12.
I have tried the code below  but it is not working!

```
from random import randint
l = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
p = []
count = 0

for i in range(10000):
     a  = randint(1,6)
     b  = randint(1,6)
     for j in l:
         if a+b == j:
         count+=1
         percent = (count/10000)*100
         p.append(percent)
print(p)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [ask]. "Not working" doesn't really constitute a question. What is it doing, and how does that differ from what you want? (By going through the steps to make your question specific, you may even find you answer it yourself!)

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Why update `p` inside two for loops? That list will be 110,000 items long after the end of this.

Comment: @EricJin: This is exactly why we need the OP to update the indentation. Is the append to `p` inside one or two loops? (or none at all)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Your code has a bug at the indentation and some logic. You can try this code below. I have fixed your logic as shown below

```
from random import randint
l = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
count = [0]*len(l) # initialise count for each result
TOTAL_ROUND = 10000 

for i in range(TOTAL_ROUND):
        a  = randint(1,6)
        b  = randint(1,6)
        index = (a+b) - 2 # get index for each result
        count[index] += 1 
percent = [c/ TOTAL_ROUND * 100 for c in count] # calculate percentage
print(percent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using a generator expression and dictionary comprehension:

```
rolls = (randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in range(10000))
total = {i:0 for i in range(2, 13)}
for i in rolls:
    total[i]+=1
percentage = {i: 100*j/10000 for i, j in total.items()}
percentage
```

Output:

```
{2: 2.74,
 3: 5.61,
 4: 8.09,
 5: 11.55,
 6: 14.45,
 7: 16.57,
 8: 14.0,
 9: 10.97,
 10: 8.18,
 11: 5.21,
 12: 2.63}
```

As pointed out in the comments, using `collections.Counter` in place of the for loop is faster:

```
import collections
rolls = (randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in range(N))
total = collections.Counter(rolls)
percentage = {i: 100*j/N for i, j in total.items()}
percentage
```

Benchmark:

```
import timeit
def for_loop(n):
    rolls = (randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in range(n))
    total = {i:0 for i in range(2, 13)}
    for i in rolls:
        total[i]+=1
    percentage = {i: 100*j/n for i, j in total.items()}
    return percentage
def counter(n):
    rolls = (randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in range(n))
    total = collections.Counter(rolls)
    percentage = {i: 100*j/n for i, j in total.items()}
    return percentage

N = 10000
%timeit for_loop(N)
%timeit counter(N)
```

Output:

```
12.4 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
11.8 ms ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Or if you really care about speed, you could change the generator expression to a list comprehension and use numba:

```
import numba
@numba.njit
def numba_for_loop(n):
    rolls = [randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in range(n)]
    total = {i:0 for i in range(2, 13)}
    for i in rolls:
        total[i]+=1
    percentage = {i: 100*j/n for i, j in total.items()}
    return percentage
```

```
N = 10000
%timeit numba_for_loop(N)
```

Output:

```
527 µs ± 38.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can use `collections. Counter` to replace `for-loop` - that's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation errors aside, you're not manipulating the count properly.

You are incrementing the global variable `count`, instead of one for every possible dice roll you can get in the range 2..12.

The final calculation for the percentage should also be done outside of the loop, only once for every possible roll.

```py
from random import randint

# There's no need to store the possible outputs into here.
# Instead, l[2..12] is how many times it has been shown
# The first two elements are irrelevant because you'll never get `0` or `1`
l = [None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
p = []
count = 0

for i in range(10000):
    a = randint(1,6)
    b = randint(1,6)
    # Increment the number of times we've seen this role by 1
    l[a+b] += 1

# For every value from 2 to 12, put its % into `p`
for i in range(2, 13):
    percent = l[i] / 10000 *100
    p.append(percent)
print(p)
```

The output (which is about what you would expect):

```
#  2    3      4      5      6            7            8      9                    10               11      12
[2.39, 5.83, 8.32, 11.59, 13.51, 16.950000000000003, 14.31, 10.530000000000001, 7.920000000000001, 5.57, 3.08]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code had problems with indentation. I have fixed them.

```
from random import randint
l = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
p = []
count = 0
for i in range(10000):
      a  = randint(1,6)
      b  = randint(1,6)
      for j in l:
          if a+b == j:
            count+=1
            percent = (count/10000)*100
            p.append(percent)
print(len(p))

#output
10000
```

Comment: Since there are indentation problems you cannot know what the intention of the OP is. How can you know you have fixed them?

Comment: So why do you think that a) fixed indentation fixes the problems with the code or b) `print(len(p))` is anything like printing a percentage?

Comment: Based on the asker's description, there should be exactly eleven percentages. One for how many rolls added up to 2, one for how many added up to 3, and so on up through 12. Ten thousand percentages is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's me giving it a go using a dictionary instead of two lists.

```
>>> l = {2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
>>> from random import randint
>>> for i in range(10000):
...     a = randint(1,6)
...     b = randint(1,6)
...     l[a+b] += 1/10000 * 100
...
>>> l
{2: 2.8299999999999836, 3: 5.869999999999919, 4: 8.079999999999872, 5: 10.53999999999982, 6: 13.459999999999757, 7: 17.189999999999888, 8: 14.619999999999733, 9: 11.02999999999981, 10: 8.049999999999873, 11: 5.599999999999925, 12: 2.7299999999999858}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint

rolls = {}
for _ in range(10_000):
    a = randint(1, 6)
    b = randint(1, 6)

    if a+b in rolls:
        rolls[a+b] += 1
    else:
        rolls[a+b] = 1

roll_percentage = {roll: (count / 10_000) * 100 for roll, count in rolls.items()}
```